# How to get organization module info, vtiger

Tags: php, sql, vtiger

I want to get info from vtiger Organization module. I got info from contacts with query `SELECT * FROM Contacts` and work great but when try `SELECT * FROM Organizations` query is not executed. In Contact module I got info for client org, account_id in format 10x12 but i need to write in frontend name of organization, not this number. Somebody to help, i will appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the Organizations module. You'll see something like this in your browser's URL box: `https://your_vtiger.com/index.php?module=Accounts&view=List`

Notice the `module=Accounts` part. It means that the name of the organizations module is, from the system's perspective, Accounts and not Organization.

So, you'd use something like this if you are doing a mysql query:

```
SELECT * FROM vtiger_account;
```

If you are using Vtiger's REST API, then it should be

```
SECLECT * FROM accounts;
```

Finally, if you want  to know the names for all Vtiger's modules, take a look at the database table `vtiger_tab`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM vtiger_account;` not `vtiger_accounts`